# Unreliable results from OrderedDict in Python

Tags: python, collections

ANSWERED

This program displays words that appear on both two text files and the words should only contain alphabets. The information printed will be the word and the frequency.

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter
f = open('P1Input1.txt', 'r')
g = open('P1Input2.txt', 'r')
data = {}
data2 = {}

for line in f:
    for word in line.split():
        if word in data:
            data[word] += 1
        else:
            if re.match("^[A-Za-z]*$", word):
                data[word] = 1
f.close()

for line in g:
    for word in line.split():
        data2[word] = 1

g.close()        
for key in data:
    if key in data2:
        data[key] += 1
    else:
        del data[key]


OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key = lambda t: t[1]))
print(data)
```

For some reason, the values keep changing and here are the results. what am i doing wrong?

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
{'is': 3, 'how': 2, 'hello': 5, 'it': 3, 'doing': 2, 'you': 2, 'a': 2, 'are': 2, 'day': 2, 'beautiful': 2}
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
{'is': 3, 'hello': 5, 'beautiful': 2, 'are': 2, 'how': 2, 'a': 2, 'you': 2, 'it': 3, 'doing': 2, 'day': 2}
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
{'hello': 5, 'a': 2, 'you': 2, 'are': 2, 'is': 3, 'it': 3, 'day': 2, 'beautiful': 2, 'how': 2, 'doing': 2}
>>>
```

Comment: You're not storing the `OrderedDict` anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OrderedDict(...)
```

This line constructs an ordered dictionary, when throws it away immediately. You don't store it anywhere, least of all in `data` which stores the original, unordered dictionary. Then you go on to print said dictionary, which of course still isn't ordered.

To change what `data` refers to, you must assign to `data`:

```
data = OrderedDict(...)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

The code creates a `OrderedDict` object in the following statement, but does not not assigned that to any variable.

```
OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key = lambda t: t[1])) # <----
print(data) # <--- `data` still references the old dict object.
```

Assign that to a variable before print it.

```
data = OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key = lambda t: t[1]))
print(data)
```